# ValueError: None values not supported

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I built a custom Keras layer which has two types of weights, learnable and non-learnable. In `build(self, input_shape)`

I add the two weight matrices, Wt and Wu, as follows.

```
self.trainable_weights = [self.Wt]
self.non_trainable_weights = [self.Wu]
self.non_trainable_weights[0].eval(K.get_session()) # why?
```

In `call(self, x, mask=None)` I do:

```
gwt = K.gather(self.Wt, x)
gwu = K.gather(self.Wu, x)
return gwu + gwt
```

My backend is TensorFlow.

The code only works if I call `eval` for the non-trainable weights. If I leave it out I get a `ValueError: None values not supported.` For the trainable weights, I don't have to call `eval`.

Whatever the effects of `eval` are, is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the values of the weights at indices indicated by x?

Tensorflow stores variables symbolically; they do not actually take on a value until runtime when they are evaluated on the session's graph. Hence, in order to get the weights, you would have to evaluate them first in order to load their values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't there a better way to load the values, instead of calling `eval`? The matrix in the trainable weights for example is usable without the call, but the matrix in the non-trainable weights is not (see my minor edit).

Comment: I'm not sure. It must have something to do with the way Wt and Wu are initialized, which would be elsewhere in the code.